# Match String in Second Level Domain Only

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match

Users enter a domain/subdomain in my script as input. I don't want to allow specific strings inside the domain but allow them inside the subdomain (if a subdomain is used).

Here's a sample user input:

[allow the bad word here].[don't allow the bad word here].[tld]

[don't allow the bad word here].[tld]

Note that TLDs may consist of a single part (.com) or multiple parts (.co.uk), which should be taken into account. For this reason a simple regex won't do the trick.

Also, the bad word may be before, after or in between the domain or the subdomain itself.

Comment: That's cool. But [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: @Rikesh I've tried regex but that's not a good solution due to `co.uk` domains for example.

Comment: What have you tried, indeed? To give you a hint: you'll need a list of valid [top-level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) and [country code second-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcSLD) for any routine to work reliably.

Comment: One such (perhaps a bit too elaborate) list is [available here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) at Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

Following your examples:

```
"^[^.]*bad[^.]*\.[^.]+$"
```

If it matches, it should not be allowed.

If you need a more generic answer though, you'll have to dig a bit more.

**Edit:**
If you have a list of second-level domain names:

```
"bad[^.]*\.(co.uk|com|...)$"
```

This could be pretty slow though maybe. Could be better to match bad, and then check if the second-level domain name is in the list.

Comment: This matches `bad.domain.com` whereas this should be allowed.

Comment: @ColorWP.com misread your question as I took `verybad.co.uk` as an example of "2+ domain level" which leads me to agree with fireeyedboy that you need a list of the domains. Edited though.

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit. Please, check it and let me know if you can contribute with another solution.